# How can I get values from a select "as"

Tags: mysql, select, reference

I have the following and I am trying to get the value from "id_category" in the AS part. I need to reference it to built a link farther down the query

```
  case
    when  pa.category_id = 310 then 669 -- Trains
    when  pa.category_id = 309 then 2785 -- Ships
    when  pa.category_id = 311 then 631  -- Planes
  end  
      else concat("NOT FOUND FOR ",pc.name)
  end **as "id_category",**
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get it in a outer query like

```
select id_category, ...
from (
 select case
    when  pa.category_id = 310 then 669 -- Trains
    when  pa.category_id = 309 then 2785 -- Ships
    when  pa.category_id = 311 then 631  -- Planes
      else concat("NOT FOUND FOR ",pc.name)
  end as "id_category" from table1) xxx;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only us the id_category in the **order by** statement. If you want to use it in another place try to use a subquery

```
Select SUBQUERY.id_category
from ( select 

case
    when  pa.category_id = 310 then 669 -- Trains
    when  pa.category_id = 309 then 2785 -- Ships
    when  pa.category_id = 311 then 631  -- Planes
  end  
      else concat("NOT FOUND FOR ",pc.name)
  end **as "id_category",**
...
) AS 'SUBQUERY'
...
```